# mysql_query does not return anything

Tags: mysql

I am using the following code, it does not display anything but just a new line. What could be wrong? Thanks.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo($result."<br>");
```

The whole code,

```
<?php 
include 'dbc.php';
$LeadFirstName = $_POST['LeadFirstName'];
$LeadFirstName = $_POST['LeadFirstName'];
$LeadEmail =$_POST['LeadEmail'];
$LeadEmail2 =$_POST['LeadEmail2'];
$LeadPhone =$_POST['LeadPhone'];
$LeadCity =$_POST['LeadCity'];
$LeadAddress =$_POST['LeadAddress'];
$LeadPostcode =$_POST['LeadPostcode'];
$LeadUserId =$_POST['LeadUserId'];
$LeadLeadStatusId =$_POST['LeadLeadStatusId'];
$LeadMonth =$_POST['LeadMonth'];
$LeadAreas =$_POST['LeadAreas'];
$LeadMinPrice =$_POST['LeadMinPrice'];
$LeadMaxPrice =$_POST['LeadMaxPrice'];
$LeadMinBedrooms =$_POST['LeadMinBedrooms'];
$LeadMaxBedrooms =$_POST['LeadMaxBedrooms'];
$LeadMinBathrooms =$_POST['LeadMinBathrooms'];
$LeadMaxBathrooms =$_POST['LeadMaxBathrooms'];
$LeadMinYear =$_POST['LeadMinYear'];
$LeadNextFollowup_mm =$_POST['LeadNextFollowup_mm'];
$LeadNextFollowup_dd =$_POST['LeadNextFollowup_dd'];
$LeadNextFollowup =$_POST['LeadNextFollowup'];
$sql="INSERT INTO 'realtorl_leads'.`data (`LeadFirstName`, `LeadLastName`, `LeadEmail`, `LeadEmail2`, `LeadPhone`, `LeadCity`, `LeadAddress`, `LeadPostcode`, `LeadUserId`, `LeadLeadStatusId`, `LeadMonth`, `LeadAreas`, `LeadMinPrice`, `LeadMaxPrice`, `LeadMinBedrooms`, `LeadMaxBedrooms`, `LeadMinBathrooms`, `LeadMaxBathrooms`, `LeadMinYear`, `LeadNextFollowup_mm`, `LeadNextFollowup_dd`, `LeadNextFollowup`) VALUES ($LeadFirstName, $LeadLastName, $LeadEmail, $LeadEmail2, $LeadPhone, $LeadCity, $LeadAddress, $LeadPostcode, $LeadUserId, $LeadLeadStatusId, $LeadMonth, $LeadAreas, $LeadMinPrice, $LeadMaxPrice, $LeadMinBedrooms, $LeadMaxBedrooms, $LeadNextFollowup_mm, $LeadNextFollowup_dd, $LeadNextFollowup)";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo($result."<br>");
if (mysql_affected_rows($result)){
  echo("worked");
}else {
  echo("does not work");
}
?>
```

Comment: Try with `mysql_affected_rows()` instead of `mysql_affected_rows($result)`.

Comment: @sarwar026: Tried. Does not work.

Comment: Please see my answer below

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com). Also, [`mysql_*` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) should not be used in new applications and will be removed from future versions of PHP. Please consider switching to [**`MySQLi`** or **`PDO`**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). As written, someone could ruin your entire website in seconds.

Comment: [Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a ` sign in the query.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO 'realtorl_leads'.`data (`LeadFirstName`, 
                                        ^
```

Correct query will be

```
$sql="INSERT INTO 'realtorl_leads'.`data` (`LeadFirstName`,
```

It should work now.

Comment: If `realtorl_leads` is a database name, it should be enclosed in backticks as well, not in apostrophes.